# How can I improve my code, and why does it not run?

Tags: javascript

This code is meant to take a number score from 0 to 100 and print the grade.

This is for school and is using a simplified version of javascript from the website 'codehs.com' I've been stuck on this for a while now, I would like help fixing my code.

```
/* This code is meant to take a number score from 0 to 100 and print 
the grade. */

function start(){

 /*given list */

lettergrade(100);
lettergrade(83);
lettergrade(68);
lettergrade(91);
lettergrade(47);
lettergrade(79);
}
/* this will print the grades above by using If/else if statements */
function lettergrade(score){

if(score = 90-100){
return("A");
}
else if(score = 80-90){
return("B");
}
else if(score = 70-79){
return("C");
}
else if(score = 60-69){
return("D");
}
else if(score = 0-59){
return("F");
   }
}
```

The Expected result is to print the letter grades, A-F and the +/- sign if needed, but the code does not run.

Comment: The actual result is nothing happens because your code runs fine, it just doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: You've got a couple of errors.  As mel says, your code doesn't print anything.  Also, to check for equality, you need ==, not =.  And you can't check a range by saying "if (score == 80-90)".  That just checks if score is equal to 80 minus 90.  You probably need to break this down and do some simpler functions, like just a function to check if a number is between 10 and 20, and get that right and build up to what you are trying to do.

Comment: `return` isn't a function - it's a statement. `return "A"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple places wrong with your code:

- `lettergrade(100)` is wrong because your function defined as `letterGrade`, there is case sensitivity in JS
- `if(score = 90-99)` is wrong because `if` statement is expecting expression which you can choose to use `==` or `===`. Single equal sign `=` meant for value assignment, not for comparison. And `90-99` is wrong, that is calculation not range. Correct way should be `if(score >= 90 && score <= 99)`

```js
/* this will print the grades above by using If/else if statements */
function letterGrade(score){

if(score >= 90 && score <= 99){
  return("A");
}
else if(score >= 80 && score < 90){
  return("B");
}
else if(score >= 70 && score < 80){
  return("C");
}
else if(score >= 60 && score < 70){
  return("D");
}
else if(score >= 0 && score < 60){
  return("F");
}
  }

function start(){

 /*given list */

console.log(letterGrade(100));
console.log(letterGrade(83));
console.log(letterGrade(68));
console.log(letterGrade(91));
console.log(letterGrade(47));
console.log(letterGrade(79));
}



start();
```

Comment: This code returns `undefined` for `100` and several other values.

Comment: @Herohtar: Yes of course, because it's expected that way based on the original condition given.

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax is full of errors
2. Watch out for case sensitivity
3. You want an else statement to check if score is not valid

```
function letterGrade(score){
    if(score >= 90 && score <= 100) {
        return "A";
    }
    else if(score >= 80 && score < 90){
        return "B";
    }
    else if(score >= 70 && score <= 79){
        return "C";
    }
    else if(score >= 60 && score <= 69){
        return "D";
    }
    else if(score >= 0 && score <= 59){
        return "F";
    }
    else {
        console.error(`Err: ${score} is not a valid score`);
    }
}
```

Normal usage :

```
console.log(letterGrade(85)); // "B"
console.log(letterGrade(100)); // "A"
console.log(letterGrade(1)); // "F"
```

Handle errors :

```
console.log(letterGrade(4242)); // "Err: 4242 is not a valid Score"
console.log(letterGrade(-42)); // "Err: -42 is not a valid Score"
console.log(letterGrade("Hello World!")); // "Err: "Hello World!" is not a valid Score"
```